# Remove WSDL from SoapUI project without removing test suite [To reduce size of SoapUI project file]

Tags: web-service, soapui

I have a SoapUI project which includes both the WSDL and the test suites. But the size is pretty large. Is there a way to remove the wsdl, retaining the test suites so that the size would be less. I want something like the behaviour of JMeter which just holds the requests and validations. Is there any way I can do this in SOAPUI?

Comment: how large is large? Most of my projects are kb in size...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why you're doing this, but if you mean to remove it from the project, you can [right-click on the WSDL interface and choose "Remove"](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/reference/WSDL-interface.html).

[image: the right click from an interface]

Comment: True, it seems that after you have created a test suite, you might no longer need the "wsdl generated" node in your project.  I've never tried deleting it though.